# Use a String as a conditional in java (Convert String to boolean)

Tags: java, string, conditional-statements, bluej

I am new here!

I am doing a school project where I take a .csv file as input and read every line of values and store them into a String[], and then create an ArrayList.

The CSV file has some temperature measurements and I'm required to make filters for the different temperature measurements. What I want to know if there is a way to make the condition of an if statement the value of a string.

Since there are different ways to filter the information (>,<,>=,<=, from int x to int y) I want to create a method that concatenates a string that creates the condition the user is looking for;

> 1. Prompts user to choose what data from the array he wants to filter by.
>
>    > (For instance option 3, which means its the data stored in String[2])
> 2. Then asks the user to choose how he wants to filter: >,<,>=,<=, from int x to int y.
> 3. Finally asks the remaining value to finish the comparison.
>
>    From these prompts we could build:
>
>    > `String a = String[2] + (comparison operator) + comparison value.`
>    >
>    > For example `a = String[2] + " > 20"`

Then I want to use the 'a' like this:  `if(a){}`

Where the console should read this as: - - - - - - -  `if(Double.valueOf(String[2]) > 20){}`

My IDE is BlueJ which tells me incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to boolean. 
You may wonder why I use a String[] if I'm comparing double values,

Thanks in advance and my apologies if my idea is preposterous or not clear.

Comment: I think you'd be happier with something like `if (compare(key, condition, value))`. The `compare` function would filter `key` column by `value`, choosing which comparison operator to use based on `condition`. That way you wouldn't have to compile user-generated code (which is messy and, in real applications, a security vulnerability).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to evaluate conditions from Strings you could use something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        try {
            Boolean eval = (Boolean) engine.eval("40 > 10");
            assert(eval);
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not "comparing double values", and in fact you aren't comparing anything at all. A string is a string, not a true/false value, hence the incompatible types error. (To clarify, Java sees a string: `if("Double.valueOf(String[2]) > 20"){}` not `if(Double.valueOf(String[2]) > 20){}`)

I would probably just use a switch on the comparison operator (make sure it's a string not a char):

```
switch(operator) {
    case ">":
        doStuffGreaterThan();
        break;  // Needed or else it will continue into the next cases too
    case "<":
        doStuffLessThan();
        break;
    case ">=":
        doStuffGE();
        break;
    ... etc ...
}
```

Edit: I did a bit of searching and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java), which I haven't seen before but may be useful.